# Ready function in jquery

Tags: jquery

please let me know what is wrong with this code. it is not showing alert.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("button").click(function () {
          alert("hi");
      });
     });
    </script>

<form id="theform">
     <input type="text" name="dt" id="id" value="" />
     <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("button")
```

Should be

```
$("input[type=button]")    OR      $("input[name=submit]")
```

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RHb7W/)

The selector was not proper in the first place..

```
$('#btn')   // If id of the button is btn

$('.btn')   // If class of the button is btn
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'button' type tag in your html. it is input tag. please rewrite it as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    alert("hi");
  });
});
​
```

Comment: There _is_ a `<button>` element - just not in the OP's markup.

Comment: i mean there is no button type tag in his markups.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to implement this doesn't have to do with a click action on the submit button.  It's to hook in to the submit action on the form.  Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#theform").submit(function () {
    alert("hi");
  });
});
```